# How to not render element if it's null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render news feed. Articles can have titles, pictures, and author names. I render it like this:

```
render() {
    const newsItem = (article, id) => (
      <article className="news-item" key={id}>
        <img className="news-picture" src={`${article.urlToImage}`} alt=""/>
        <h1 className="news-title">{article.title}</h1>
        <p>Author: {article.author}</p>
      </article>
    );

    const newsFeed = this.state.news.map(e => newsItem(e, pushid()));

    return (
      <div className="news-feed">{newsFeed}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Some times API doesn't give author names (the value is null), and if so, I don't want to render

```
<p>Author: {article.author}</p>
```

How is it done correctly in react?

Comment: What you mean by `null`. Empty string or actual `null`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
{article.author && <p>Author: {article.author}</p>}
```

This means that if `article.author` exists or is not null then render `<p>...</p>`.

This is the same as it would have been with an `if` statement, except that you can't write if statements here. This is the equal of that.

```
if(article.author) return <p>Author: {article.author}</p>
```

Comment: @MaxPopov just updated the answer with the explanation

Comment: thanks, I know how does && work. just needed to know, how to implement it in the right way in react. Thankfully, now i know that I need to use { }

Answer (score 2):

Just check existence with [**short circuiting &&**](https://codeburst.io/javascript-short-circuit-conditionals-bbc13ac3e9eb)

```
{ article.author &&  <p>Author: {article.author}</p> }
```

How it works ?

```
x && y
|
|___________ if x true move ahead and execute `y` else don't
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
const newsItem = (article, id) => {
  if (!article.author) {
    return null;
  }
  <article className="news-item" key={id}>
    <img className="news-picture" src={`${article.urlToImage}`} alt=""/>
    <h1 className="news-title">{article.title}</h1>
    <p>Author: {article.author}</p>
  </article>
```

};

```
const newsFeed = this.state.news.map(e => newsItem(e, pushid()));

return (
  <div className="news-feed">{newsFeed}</div>
);
```

}
}

Just put the if condition as mentioned above.
So that if it is null you can return null.